# Why I can't delete my default stock and source in the MSI?

Tags: magento2, inventory, multi-source-inventory, msi

I've tried to remove the default stock and source, why I'm not allowed to do it?

[image: Magento 2 MSI removing default stock]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't delete it because:

> Any Sales Channels not assigned to a custom stock are **assigned to the Default Stock**.

- Reference: [DevDocs Adding a New Stock](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory-stock-add.html)

> When you delete the stock, all assigned web sites are **assigned to the Default Stock**. We recommend reassigning websites to other stocks prior to deletion.

- Reference: [DevDocs Deleting Stocks](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory-stock-delete.html)